# How do I merge objects back together after a SelectMany in System.Linq.Dynamic or maybe different solution all together?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to select out a couple of fields in a collection inside of collection. Roles->Users (name and ID)  I was able to get flattened data using select many, but now I need to merge it back to a collection objects so my json is formatted correctly.  I would like to do this in dynamic linq if possible otherwise I will might have to manually merge the objects back together.  Any help would be great.

User->User_Roles->Roles  (many to many relationship with User_Role as the join table)

```
q = query.SelectMany("USER_ROLES","new (inner as myUSER,outer as myROLE) ").SelectD("new (myROLE.ID as ROLE_ID, new( myROLE.NAME, myUSER.USER.FIRSTNAME,myUSER.USER.ID)as user)")
```

The results look like this:

```
 Role A-> User A
 Role A-> User B    ..notice the repeat of "Role A" 
 Role A-> User C
```

it should be

```
     Role A -> User A
             + User B
             + User C
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a JSON noob, but lets say you allready have a collection of the items

```
Role A-> User A
Role A-> User B
Role A-> User C
Role B-> User D
Role B-> User E
Role B-> User F
Role C-> User G
Role C-> User H
Role C-> User I
```

Lets name it

```
UserRoleCollection
```

just use

```
var res = UserRoleCollection.GroupBy(item => item.Role);
```

You will get an `IGrouping<TRole, TUser>` looking like this

```
Role A ->     User A
              User B
              User C
Role A ->     User D
              User E
              User F
... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GroupBy before SelectMany to get the results you're looking for.

Something like:

```
User_Roles.GroupBy(r => r.Roles.Role)
            .Select(g => new { Role = g.Key, Users = g.SelectMany(u => u.Users.Name) });
```